# How to create a function?

Tags: r, function

I know there is a function like this:

```
x <- rnorm(90, 2, 1)
quantile(x, prob=c(0.25, 0.75), type=8)
```

But I want to create a function which has output exactly same as

```
quantile(x, prob=c(0.25, 0.75), type=8)
```

I know how to create a simple function like below.

```
f1 <- function(x) {
function() {
x + 10
}
}
```

But the thing is that in this way, I cannot apply the equation of

```
(x+1/3)*0.25 + 1/3 = first output
(x+1/3)*0.75 +1/3 = second output
```

Can you please let me know how to?

What I need as output is this below

```
 25%      75% 
1.396165 2.717208
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no point in nesting a function() call within a function() call:

```
f2 <- function(x) {
   c( first=(x+1/3)*0.25 + 1/3, second=(x+1/3)*0.75 +1/3
   }   # I'm guessing this is not really what you want.
```

Or what you probably want:

```
fQ13 <- function (x) { quantile(x, c(0.25,75), type=8) }
```

Comment: The first one is closer to what I want. But this makes too many elements.. I only need to output. Is it possible to make that thing?

Comment: Our lack of a common language is getting in the way of effective communication. Can you show in an edit to your question what is needed?